# i dropped my phone and now there are lines on the screen and i can't access the screen

Tags: iphone, hardware

I had my phone in my pocket and it dropped on the tiles in my house. Now there are lines and I can't access the screen or get into my phone.

Comment: Then take it to a repair shop. Also, what do the tags Yosemite & Backup have to do with the question?

Answer (score 2):

You need to bring it to the repair shop, as the screen and sensor is damaged.

Probably all other components are left intact, so you'll not loose your data, it's normally the screen is the most weak and fragile part. Anyways - you had the backups in your account, they are done automatically by Apple, so you can restore the data.

If it's still ok, you may try to access the phone via your iMac and iTunes, and still do basic operations, alike sending SMS.

Answer (score 0):

Outch, sorry to read that,

You may want to plug your iPhone with a computer, start iTunes and backup your phone.

Then you can chat Apple Support https://www.apple.com/ie/support/contact/ in order to check the repair option available in your area.